# How to create a table with values given by user (with scanf)?

Tags: c++

I have this HW in C that I need to do, and I'm asked to replicate a table, which will be created with values given by the user:

It's supposed to look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Name             Prenume      Grupe    Data nasterii
-----------------------------------------------------
Marinescu        Alexandru     1234       10.10.2000
Georgescu        Eduard        4321       11.11.1990
Constantinescu   Ion-Catalin   4424        5.11.1995
```

I started with this, but since our proff didn't really guide us towards a way to create a table, i do not really know how to continue. It will be much appreciated if you could help, as I would enlighten some of my classmates, as well. (also, searching the web for a solution proved to be useless)

I started with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()    
{
    char nume[20], prenume[20], data[20];
    int grupa;

    printf("Introdu datele studentului nr 1:");

    printf("\nNume:");
    scanf("%s", &nume);

    printf("\nPrenume:");
    scanf("%s", &prenume);

    printf("\nGrupa:");
    scanf("%d", &grupa);

    printf("\nData nasterii:");
    scanf("%s", &data);

    printf("\nIntrodu datele studentului nr 2:");

    printf("\nNume:");
    scanf("%s", &nume);

    printf("\nPrenume:");
    scanf("%s", &prenume);

    printf("\nGrupa:");
    scanf("%d", &grupa);

    printf("\nData nasterii:");
    scanf("%s", &data);

    printf("\nIntrodu datele studentului nr 3:");

    printf("\nNume:");
    scanf("%s", &nume);

    printf("\nPrenume:");
    scanf("%s", &prenume);

    printf("\nGrupa:");
    scanf("%d", &grupa);

    printf("\nData nasterii:");
    scanf("%s", &data);

}
```

Comment: 1) `using namespace std;` is not C.  2) Post relevant data here as text rather than link to a picture.  Else this is unclear.

Comment: @chux I've added an edit suggestion where I've entered data, from the picture in the link, into the question itself.

Comment: My bad, I should have specified we're working with both c/c++. Also, thank you for your edit, @Ludvig,

Comment: @DavidBowiesamasenseisenpai Then add c++ as a tag. :)

Comment: You should dump this class.  1) `scanf` is evil and has buffer overrun issues and should not be used. 2) Your class information doesn't know whether it is C or C++, as there is no C/C++ language.  3) Character arrays suffer from buffer overruns and since this is C++ you should be taught the `std::string` class for text.  4) The `main` function returns and integer and your `main` function doesn't.  Look for another class.

Comment: If you are only printing text with `printf`, I recommend using `puts` instead.  The `printf` has to scan the given text for formatting characters which takes extra time.  The `puts` will output each character, without scanning, until a nul is found; much more efficient.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you very much for your corrections and suggestions. Regarding the class issue, yeah.. you are kind of right, you'd be surprised how many restrictions we have when coding, in ex. :don't use global variables, no cin, no cout... etc. Restrictions when it comes to programming is the most idiotic idea ever...

Comment: By The Way (BTW), your second input of data overwrites the data from the first input session.  If you want to store the data, you should use a container of structures, e.g. a `std::vector`.  An alternative is to use different sets of variables, one unique set per row.

Answer (score 0):

For printing a table, I suggest using the `cout.width` function to set the column widths.  Also use `left` or `right` to set the justification.

Don't use tabs for columns, as tab interpretation is not consistent (e.g. some tabs range from 2 to 8 spaces; or may move to the next tab stop wherever it is set).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  std::cout.width(16);
  std::cout << "Hello"
            << "There"
            << "It's"
            << "Raining\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you must use the C-Style I/O, you can use *format specifiers* to layout the text:

```
printf("%20s  %16s  %-20s %-32s\n",
       "Hello", "There", "It's", "Raining");
```

As for printing "bars" there are many methods do this, which I leave as an exercise for the OP.